# Suppose we have two dice one fair and one tha brings $6$ with quintuple probability.Find the probability to throw randomly one die and show $6$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose we have two dice one fair and one that brings $6$ with quintuple probability than the other numbers.We get a die randomly and we throw it.What is the probability to have $6$?In the same problem if we know that we have $6$ what is the probability that we have throwed the second die?

Any ideas for these  parts especially the second one?

Answer (score 1):

The probability of rolling 6 on the fair die is obviously $\frac{1}{6}$.

Let $x$ denote the probability of rolling 6 on the non-fair die:

- Then $\frac{1}{5}x$ is the probability of rolling each one of the other $5$ values
- Therefore $x+5\cdot\frac{1}{5}x=1$, therefore $2x=1$, therefore $x=\frac{1}{2}$

So the probability of rolling 6 on the non-fair die is $\frac{1}{2}$.

---

> What is the probability of rolling 6?

Split it into disjoint events, and then add up their probabilities:

- The probability of choosing the fair die and then rolling 6 on that die is $\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{12}$
- The probability of choosing the non-fair die and then rolling 6 on that die is $\frac12\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}$

So the probability of rolling 6 is $\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{3}$.

---

> If we know that we rolled 6, what is the probability that it was on the non-fair die?

Use Bayes formula for *conditional probability*:

- Let $A$ denote the event of rolling the non-fair die
- Let $B$ denote the event of rolling 6

So $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{3}{4}$.

Comment: I think you must add the assumption, for the first part, that the distribution of taking one dice or the other is uniform. I think that the better answer is just write the solution in therms of $p$ and $(1-p)$.

Comment: Ultimately, all textbook problems depend on unstated assumptions. I think this answer makes sensible assumptions. Also, while we're being picky, I think it's 'one die' and 'two dice'.

Comment: @Masacroso: You could just as well claim that the question doesn't specify how many sides on each die, so we should assume $d_1$ sides for the first die and $d_2$ sides for the second die. I don't think that's the purpose of the question though.

Comment: The probability of choosing the fair die and then rolling 6 on that die isn't $1/6$? because we know already that we for the fair die we have this probability

Comment: @MantolInis: And how do we know that it's a $6$-sided die? A die can have any number of sides, and still be fair. We assume that it's a $6$-sided die because that's how it usually is, unless mentioned otherwise (and there are plenty questions on this website where **it is** mentioned otherwise. Same thing goes for the probability of choosing each one of those dice (again - unless mentioned otherwise). It's a matter of opinion of course, but reading this question, it seems pretty obvious that the OP is asking for a precise numerical answer (IMO).

Answer (score 0):

HINT: put a name at each random variable. By example $D\in\{d1,d2\}$ is the random variable of picking one dice or the other, and $T\in\{1,2,...,6\}$ is the random variable to get some value on the throw.

And we know that

$$\Pr[T=6|D=d1]=1/6\quad\text{ and }\quad\Pr[T=6|D=d2]=1/2$$

Now we want to evaluate

1) $\Pr[T=6]$, and

2) $\Pr[D=d2|T=6]$

Comment: this hint is for the second part?

Comment: @MantolInis the hint is for both parts... see the numbers 1) and 2).

Comment: gonna try them and get back to show results

Comment: @MantolInis I get a little mistake in the interpretation of the problem sorry, the probability $\Pr[T=6|D=d2]=\frac{5p}{10p}=1/2$